# MongoDB filtered replication collection

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have capped local MongoDB collection A, and I'd like to replicate to a MongoDB collection B on a cloud server. Now, I want to keep the documents from A that will be deleted due to its capped size.

```
 Collection A      replicate      Collection B
--------------    ---------->    --------------
Capped at 50MB                   Infinite size!
local                            cloud server
```

Is this possible in MongoDB (as it is possible in CouchDB using filters)?

Or should I search for a totally different approach?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

The deletes in a capped collection are not operations, and so they are not replicated via the oplog.  Hence, all you need to do is make the collection non-capped on a secondary and it will simply continue to grow as you add data to the capped collection and those ops are replicated.  Try something like this:

1. Add the secondary on the cloud server as normal
2. Stop that new secondary, restart it outside the set with no replset argument
3. Drop the capped collection, recreate with same name as a regular non-capped collection
4. (Optional) Re-import the data manually using mongodump/mongorestore
5. Restart the secondary with the original replica set parameters
6. The new normal collection will just keep growing

If you want to delete the collection or make other changes you will need to take the secondary out each time, but otherwise this should behave as you want.  I haven't done this myself explicitly, but I have seen this happen accidentally and had to do the reverse :)